# python2.7: no such file or directory after brew upgrade python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew

After doing `brew update` and `brew upgrade python3`, I've been having such as `bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: no such file or directory`. e.g.:

```
⇒  mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3 labrador

mkvirtualenv:78: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: no such file or directory
write() failed: Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: If you upgrade your Python3 , why do you expect finding Python2? Furthermore I believe that they renamed `python3` in homebrew. I think is only called `python`. So do `brew install python`. And if you want to execute you still have to use `python3` in your shell.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities here.

---

First, [as of Homebrew 1.5](https://brew.sh/2018/01/19/homebrew-1.5.0/), the `python3` recipe was renamed `python`, and the `python` recipe is now available as `python@2`. See [the current docs](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python) on how things are organized.

While `brew` tries to make this just work like magic, if you had a really old install, or just a really complicated setup, with both `python` and `python3` from Homebrew, and you `brew upgrade python3`, you can end up with only the new (3.x) `python` recipe where you expect it to be.

To fix this one:

```
brew install python@2
```

---

Second, you may have had a virtualenv installed into a non-Homebrew Python that's confused about where to find things.

The easiest fix here is to uninstall that `virtualenv` and `pip install` it with the Homebrew 3.x Python.

More generally, if you have other Python versions besides Homebrew 3.7, Homebrew 2.7, and Apple pre-installed 2.7, unless you have a good reason to need them, you might want to scrap them. And also, if you've installed any other Python packages into Apple's 2.7, you might want to uninstall those and make sure to never touch the Apple install and only use the Homebrew 2.7.

Or, if you *do* need lots of Python installs around, you should get used to running tools with `<specific-python> -m  tool` instead of just `tool`. It's hard to keep all the different script and symlinks in sync, and way too easy to end up using a `pip` that you think matches `python` but actually installs into a completely different one, and a `virtualenv` that uses yet another one, and so on.

Comment: For whatever reason, I needed to do `brew uninstall python@2` then `brew install python@2`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in my case was:

```
pip uninstall virtualenv
pip install virtualenv
```

This was because, version of `virtualenv` and `python` were out of sync, but `python` and `pip` were still together:

```
$ virtualenv
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

$ python --version
Python 3.7.0

$ pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Both `python` and `pip` are 3.7, but `virtualenv` expected 2.7.

Un and Reinstall using `pip` (which expected 3.7) resulted in a `virtualenv` in the same version.

Answer (score 0):

tried a few things that didn't work.. in my case this is what worked:

`cd /usr/local/opt/python/bin/
ln -nfs /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python python2.7`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue:

```
pre-commit is not in your $PATH; setting one up for you
Using virtualenv: /Users/jwilliams/.indy/venvs/pre-commit-venv_macosx-10.13-x86-64_cp2.7
$ cd /Users/jwilliams/repos/terraform-aws; /Users/jwilliams/.indy/venvs/pre-commit-venv_macosx-10.13-x86-64_cp2.7/bin/pre-commit install -f --install-hooks
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/jwilliams/.indy/venvs/pre-commit-venv_macosx-10.13-x86-64_cp2.7/bin/python2.7
  Reason: image not found

$ cd /Users/jwilliams/repos/terraform-aws; /Users/jwilliams/.indy/venvs/pre-commit-venv_macosx-10.13-x86-64_cp2.7/bin/pre-commit install -f --install-hooks --hook-type pre-push
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/jwilliams/.indy/venvs/pre-commit-venv_macosx-10.13-x86-64_cp2.7/bin/python2.7
  Reason: image not found
```

I followed the above steps and got the same error. The fix in my case was to delete the `~/.indy directory`, and this forced `indy` to rebuild symlinks.